# Does biblatex-chicago not support editortype "reviser"?

Tags: biblatex

`biblatex` allows for the specification of multiple editorial roles through the availability of multiple editor keys `editor`, `editora`, `editorb`, coupled with editorial role values `translator`, `collaborator`, `reviser`, etc. linked to a series of editorial role keys `editortype`, `editoratype`, `editorbtype`.

I use `biblatex-chicago` (notes). Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Brill}
\addbibresource{season.bib}

\begin{document}

I cite.\autocite[55]{nec62lie}

\end{document}
```

And couple this with the following bibliography:

```
@book{nec62lie,
   editor = {Neckel, Gustav},
   editora = {Kuhn, Hans},
   editoratype = {reviser},
   title = {Die Lieder des Codex Regius nebst verwandten Denkmälern},
   shorttitle = {Codex Regius},
   edition = {3},
   location = {Heidelberg},
   publisher = {Winter},
   year = {1962},
   keywords = {primary}
}
```

I expect this to work. However, the output is

> 1. Gustav Neckel, ed., Die Lieder des Codex Regius nebst verwandten Denkmälern, 3rd ed., **cbyreviser**Hans Kuhn (Heidelberg: Winter, 1962), 55.

If I change the value of `editoratype` from `reviser` to `collaborator`, it works beautifully. And yes, I have tried whether `biblatex-chicago` prefers the spelling "revisor".

Does `biblatex-chicago` not support the role `reviser`? What can I do to make this work?

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` by default does not define `cbyreviser`. So we have to provide that string. What would you like it to say? Try `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{cbyreviser = {whatevergoeshere},}` (`\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{cbyreviser = {whatevergoeshere},}` for German etc.) in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks! However, this solution yields the following error:
`Package xkeyval Error: \`cbyreviser' undefined in families \`blx@lbx'.` 
and my output accordingly remains the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah got it, I had to `\NewBibliographyString{cbyreviser}` first. Would you like to upgrade your comment to an answer? It's fixed my problem after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we use `editoratype = {reviser}` `biblatex-chicago` tries to print the undefined bibstring `cbyreviser`.

So all we have to do is to create the bibstring `cbyreviser`.

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbyreviser}
```

and populate it with appropriate text

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  cbyreviser = {rev\adddot},
}
```

As a general rule of thumb: If one gets bold output<sup>*</sup> and a warning similar to

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'cbyreviser' undefined
> (biblatex)                at entry 'nec62lie' on input line 35.
> ```

the problem lies with `biblatex` trying to print a bibstring that is not defined; in that case declaring the string and defining it as above is a good way to start tackling the problem.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nec62lie,
   editor = {Neckel, Gustav},
   editora = {Kuhn, Hans},
   editoratype = {reviser},
   title = {Die Lieder des Codex Regius nebst verwandten Denkmälern},
   shorttitle = {Codex Regius},
   edition = {3},
   location = {Heidelberg},
   publisher = {Winter},
   year = {1962},
   keywords = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyreviser}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  cbyreviser = {rev\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
  I cite.\autocite[55]{nec62lie}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>*</sup> With `biblatex` bold output is hardly ever a good sign, it almost always means something or other went wrong.