# Customizing editor types with windycity (biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex, windycity

I am using [`windycity`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/windycity), and I have a work with an author and a reviser. I can add an `editor` field, but is there any way to customize the output so that it reads `revised by` and `rev.` rather than `edited by` and `ed.`?

There is a very similar question here for [`biblatex-chicago`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164779/does-biblatex-chicago-not-support-editortype-reviser), but that doesn't seem to work for me. I'm assuming that their internals are different in this regard.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[style=windycity,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{ dyer-apology-crito-2007,
    author = {Louis Dyer},
    title = {Plato's Apology and Crito},
    editora = {Thomas Day Seymour}, % This may be the wrong approach.
    editoratype = {reviser}, % This may be the wrong approach.
    publisher = {Aristide D. Caratzas},
    year = {2007},
    address = {New Rochelle, NY},
    keywords = {commentary,apology,crito,phaedo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][15]{dyer-apology-crito-2007}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GitHub, the author of `windycity` suggested handling this with the `note` field. To make that even a little smoother, [he suggested the following](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/issues/7#issuecomment-586769351):

> In american-windycity.lbx, add something like the following to \DeclareBibliographyStrings:
>
> ```
> revisedby     = {{revised by}{rev\adddot}},
> ```

In the same file you also need to add a preceding declaration:

```
\NewBibliographyString{revisedby}
```

Then we can use the `note` field like this:

```
note = {\bibstring{revisedby} Thomas Day Seymour}
```

That will give the desired results in both the bibliography and notes.

The author said that he will likely update `windycity` to include `revisedby`, so this whole question will be moot soon.

**UPDATE**: the author of `windycity` [has added `reviser` as a built-in editor role](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/commit/99b60a07b242b4d4a4fe1c81255877c613967930), just like `compiler` or `translator`. The update has not yet reached CTAN, but you can easily copy the files locally if you want to use it right now. This means that going forward, you don't have to use the `note` field. You can simply do the following:

```
@book{ dyer-apology-crito-2007,
    author = {Louis Dyer},
    title = {Plato's Apology and Crito},
    shorttitle = {Apology and Crito},
    editor = {Thomas Day Seymour},
    editortype = {reviser},
    publisher = {Aristide D. Caratzas},
    year = {2007},
    address = {New Rochelle, NY},
    keywords = {commentary,apology,crito,phaedo},
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The editor handling in `windycity` is quite different from what other `biblatex` styles have implemented. In particular `windycity` uses a complex set of rules to determine which editors (of which type) are shown, see [§3. *Editors, Translators, and Compilers* of the `windycity` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/windycity/doc/windycity.pdf).

The following adds support for a `reviser`, but it uses the standard `biblatex` approach to these sort of things that doesn't quite feel right here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=windycity, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{reviser}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{editortype}{reviser}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {}
       {\newunit
        \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \newunit}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{edcombos+etc}{%
  \togglefalse{noed}%
  \togglefalse{notrans}%
  \usebibmacro{test:ed}%
  \usebibmacro{test:trans}%
  \iftoggle{noed}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{edcombos}%
     \usebibmacro{pluga+etc}}%
  \usebibmacro{reviser}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{dyer-apology-crito-2007,
  author      = {Louis Dyer},
  title       = {Plato's Apology and Crito},
  editor      = {Thomas Day Seymour},
  editortype  = {reviser},
  publisher   = {Aristide D. Caratzas},
  year        = {2007},
  address     = {New Rochelle, NY},
  keywords    = {commentary,apology,crito,phaedo},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Blah, blah, blah.\footcite[][15]{dyer-apology-crito-2007}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Dyer, Louis. Plato’s Apology and Crito. Revised by Thomas Day Seymour. New Rochelle, NY: Aristide D. Caratzas, 2007.]

If the Chicago Manual of Style bibliography style allows for revisers, then I suggest you open a feature request at https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/issues.

Comment: That's two I owe you in two days: much appreciated! I also opened an issue asking for a hook to add custom editor types like reviser. We will see what the maintainer suggests.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I accepted my own answer simply because it has the most up-to-date information about `windycity` itself, but I appreciate your interim answer and the suggestion that I file a bug report.